# How to use COUNTIF and UNIQUE

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet with two columns. One containing a list with order numbers - the order numbers can be listed several times/duplicates. The other column consists of the a free text with the name of one of our delivery partners (fx. UPS or Fedex) - the partner that delivered that specific order.

I want to count the number of unique orders (column `A`) sent by a specific partner (column `B`).

I am trying to use `COUNTSIFS` with two conditions, but I only end up with an error.

Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please share a test sheet with data, expected results and efforts so far.

Comment: Solve it.

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:B; "select A where B='Fedex'"; 0)))

Comment: Great work. Now as per [sites guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) please get some more reputation and write a complete answer instead of just a comment so others can benefit as well.